# How do I construct a script to insert multiple filenames in to a (html) file?

Tags: bash, scripting, html

I'm pretty certain this will have been answered somewhere already but I can't figure out how to phrase my question to Google in such a way to find it!  My usual approach is to find a similar script and adapt it but I'm having trouble getting started with this one.  I know sed is going to be involved, though.

I have a variable (in name and number) set of video files; e.g.

```
2020_12_15-14_20_56_Event23.mkv
2020_12_15-14_24_28_Event24.mkv
2020_12_15-15_09_11_Event25.mkv
2020_12_15-15_15_26_Event26.mkv
2020_12_15-15_18_36_Event27.mkv
2020_12_15-15_42_16_Event28.mkv
2020_12_15-15_46_15_Event29.mkv
2020_12_15-15_49_48_Event30.mkv
2020_12_15-16_15_03_Event31.mkv
2020_12_15-16_20_05_Event32.mkv
```

And I'd like to cron a script that generates an html page that displays them; e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_04-13_46_45_Event23.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_04-13_46_45_Event24.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="INSERT NEXT FILE IN LIST HERE" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

(...etc)

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is possible with just bash as I'd like to keep this as pure html (no php, javascript, etc) if I can:  Run a script, pick up all the files in a directory and generate a lump of html as above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite straightforward. Simply put the header and footer in variables, and do the same for the block of text that only changes according to the file name. Then iterate over your file names, printing each as you go. Something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' header <<EoF
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

EoF

read -r -d '' footer <<EoF
</body>
</html>
EoF

read -r -d '' printfFormatString <<EoF
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="%s" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>\n\n
EoF

printf "%s\n" "$header"
for file in "$@"; do
    printf "$printfFormatString" "$file"
done
printf "%s\n" "$footer"
```

You would then run the script with the file names as arguments:

```
$ foo.sh *mkv
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-14_20_56_Event23.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-14_24_28_Event24.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-15_09_11_Event25.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-15_15_26_Event26.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-15_18_36_Event27.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-15_42_16_Event28.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-15_46_15_Event29.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-15_49_48_Event30.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-16_15_03_Event31.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="2020_12_15-16_20_05_Event32.mkv" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Many thanks for that.  Have a great day.

Comment: You're very welcome, @MarcusG.